# Both Windows & Ubuntu on HDD and installation USB won't boot now

Tags: dual-boot, boot-loader, bootable

This old DELL laptop originally comes with Windows 7, then I installed Ubuntu some time last year.
Ubuntu has been unable to boot or install or LIVE any linux distros since this April, I've tried same or newer Ubuntu, Linux Mint, etc.
After Grub selection, crazy text flows, beep, shut down. I've tried all the normal, upstart, recovery mode. Recovery mode will get to a selection menu, whichever I picked, crazy text flow, beep, shut down.
Trying to install or run LIVE any other linux distro will result in the same pattern: crazy text flow, beep, shut down. No chance to get any of the details.
I gave up on Linux.

Yesterday, I decided to go for Windows 10 and got a ghost copy and installed it. Then Windows won't boot either.
I got various error codes here, most commonly "Kernel security check failure," sometimes others.

Tried to fix, I downloaded Windows 10 ISO from Microsoft. The only other computer I have at home is running Linux Mint.
I used bootiso to create the bootable USB stick. Now it gives error message "Operating system not found" and no Windows installation menu.

Then I tried to install gparted to remove existing Ubuntu and Windows partitions. With tuxboot, I got the bootable gparted USB stick. LIVE mode simply text flow, beep, shut down. New error message and a suggestion "pnpbios=off." Some Googling, I returned to Grub menu and 'e' and appended "pnpbios=off," no luck. I also confirmed that there's no newer BIOS from Dell for this old machine.

By now, I suspect something is wrong in BIOS, or bootloader.

Whether to fix Grub or to fix Windows boot, all Googling results tells me to use Windows or Linux installation media. But none of these is able to run in my laptop. What can I do?

I want a working Windows or Linux.

Comment: I've also managed to download a Windows 7 ISO. I fetched the bootrec.exe file and created a bootable FreeDOS USB. FreeDOS runs successfully, but bootrec.exe won't run. I also tried ghost.exe, it runs but fails to restore my Windows 7 ghost copy from long time ago or downloaded Windows 10 ghost copy, I guess it's compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the BIOS, if you find that a secure boot option is on, disable it. Then if there is an option to clear the secure boot keys, do that. Reboot, and attempt the install.

If all else fails put the drive in another system. Live boot in, if the system runs, wipe the drive to all zeros then install back into the laptop. Try to install again.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mentioned that, there's no Secure Boot option, and I've already tried default BIOS settings. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I did reset all BIOS options to default, and no luck. I haven't tried removing and reinstalling BIOS battery yet. I'll tried this later.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the crazy text is trying to say?

Comment: I'd say it's just some normal booting stuff, but I can't catch the part when it beeps and shuts down, it's flowing too fast.

Comment: After you reset to all defaults did you make sure that USB boot was the first option? Also if possible remove the HDD boot option completely for testing.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both USB first and HDD first. It shouldn't be the boot order, cuz FreeDOS runs successfully, and GParted also gets to Run live or Install menu.

Comment: Did you try to install from a known working install disk or from a recently burnt untested copy? I would check the md5 sum of the disks.

Comment: One of the Win 10 disk was installed on my friend's laptop a few days ago, and it's running pretty good. That's why I decided to give Win10 a try. The other Windows or Linux ISOs are freshly downloaded and untested.